# Add multiple images to a custom block

Tags: block-editor

I've written the following custom block that allows a user to create a simple slider and add an image that is then wrapped inside a slider item element. I've opted to make this a single block rather than using nested blocks (e.g. a slider item block and parent slider) because I don't want them wrapping in additional HTML when inside the block editor and instead want it to be a single block of images (like the gallery block).

```
(function(blocks, editor, element, blockEditor, components) {
var el = element.createElement;
var MediaUpload = editor.MediaUpload;

blocks.registerBlockType('theme/slider', {
        title: 'Slider',
        icon: 'universal-access-alt',
        category: 'layout',
        example: {},
        attributes: {
            mediaID: {
                type: 'number',
            },
            mediaURL: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'attribute',
                selector: 'img',
                attribute: 'src',
            },
        },
        edit: function(props) {
            function onSelectImage(media) {
                return props.setAttributes({
                    mediaURL: media.url,
                    mediaID: media.id,
                });
            };

            return el('div', {
                    className: 'slider'
                },
                el('div', {
                        className: 'slider-item'
                    },
                    el(MediaUpload, {
                        onSelect: onSelectImage,
                        allowedTypes: 'image',
                        value: props.attributes.mediaID,
                        render: function(obj) {
                            return el(
                                components.Button, {
                                    className: props.attributes.mediaID ?
                                        'image-button' :
                                        'button button-large',
                                    onClick: obj.open,
                                },
                                !props.attributes.mediaID ?
                                'Upload Image' :
                                el('img', {
                                    src: props.attributes.mediaURL
                                })
                            );
                        },
                    }),
                }),
        );
    },
    save: function(props) {
        return el('div', {
                className: 'slider'
            }, el('div', {
                className: 'slider-item'
            }, (props.attributes.mediaURL ? el('img', {
                src: props.attributes.mediaURL
            }) : el('div')))
        },
    });
});
})(window.wp.blocks, window.wp.editor, window.wp.element, window.wp.blockEditor, window.wp.components);
```

However I'm not sure how to make both of those attributes `mediaID` and `mediaURL` repeatable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other changes you need to make in your code, but as for the main one — making the `mediaID` and `mediaURL` be repeatable, the [(core) gallery block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/gallery) did it by setting [`query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#query) as the attribute *source* and `array` as the attribute *type*.

So I would do the same and for example you can set the attribute name to `images`:

```js
// Define the attribute:
attributes: {
    images: {
        type: 'array',
        source: 'query',
        selector: '.slider-item',
        default: [],

        // The following means in each .slider-item element in the saved markup,
        // the attribute value is read from the data-id or src attribute of the
        // img element in the .slider-item element. And yes of course, you can
        // change the selector to 'a', '.some-class' or something else.
        query: {
            mediaID: {
                type: 'number',
                source: 'attribute',
                attribute: 'data-id',
                selector: 'img',
            },
            mediaURL: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'attribute',
                attribute: 'src',
                selector: 'img',
            },
        },
    },
}

/* And the attribute value would look like:
images: [
  { mediaID: 1, mediaURL: 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/image.png' },
  { mediaID: 2, mediaURL: 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/image2.png' },
  ...
]
*/
```

Then in your `MediaUpload` element, you would want to set the [`gallery` and `multiple` properties](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/media-upload#gallery) to `true` (to allow multiple image selections), and in your `onSelectImage()` function, you can set the attribute value (which is an array) like so:

```js
props.setAttributes( {
    images: items.map( item => {
        return {
            mediaID: parseInt( item.id, 10 ),
            mediaURL: item.url,
        };
    } ),
} );
```

### Try My Block/Code

So it uses JSX and ESNext, but the `save()` output is identical to the one in the question, and you can find the code [here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/633c4142b77d46068d447cceac3dbc99). :)

Comment: Thanks that's worked out perfectly :)